# React is throwing a "Objects are not valid as a React child" error in browser log while using Axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am completely new to React. I am trying to display data from my Web API.

**I am getting an error in Chrome's console**

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {nameId, modelName, tblModelDetails}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

I think the error is because I have a nested array in my JSON. I am trying to display data into a list on my browser

**Here is how my Json is being displayed in Postman:**

```
[
    {
        "modelId": 18,
        "typeId": 2,
        "rangeId": 1,
        "nameId": 1,
        "scaleId": 1,
        "info": "info",
        "picture": "Picture",
        "partNumber": 123,
        "amountOwned": 3,
        "modified": false,
        "limitedAddition": true,
        "datePurchase": "2021-01-01T00:00:00",
        "pricePaid": 10.0000,
        "upc": 99999,
        "modelSeries": null,
        "name": {
            "nameId": 1,
            "modelName": "Xerion",
            "tblModelDetails": []
        },
        "range": {
            "rangeId": 1,
            "modelRange": "Class",
            "tblModelDetails": []
        },
        "scale": {
            "scaleId": 1,
            "modelScale": "1:32",
            "tblModelDetails": []
        },
        "type": {
            "typeId": 2,
            "modelType": "Tractor",
            "tblModelDetails": []
        }
    }
]
```

**The React code I have been trying to use is:**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import axios from 'axios';

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    values: []
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    
    axios.get('https://localhost:5001/api/Model')
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response)
        this.setState({
          values: response.data
        })
      })
    }

  render(){
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <ul>
            {this.state.values.map((values: any) => (
              
              <li>{values[0]}</li>
              

            ))}
          </ul>
        </header>
      </div>
    );
  }
  }


export default App;
```

Any ideas on how I can get my Data to display?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it like that

I am just showing the `pricePaid` value from your json

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import axios from 'axios';

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    values: []
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    axios.get('https://localhost:5001/api/Model')
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response)
        this.setState({
          values: response.data
        })
      })
    }

  render(){
    if (!this.state.values.length) {
        return null;
    }

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <ul>
            {this.state.values.map((value: any) => (
              
              <li>{value.pricePaid}</li>
              

            ))}
          </ul>
        </header>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


export default App;
```

Comment: cc: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66963028 Haven't looked into it much myself, but seems a bit odd that [handler props](https://github.com/img-mapper/react-img-mapper/blob/2e03440f57f0219e99198a5ac809141473a3dca8/src/types.tsx#L75) aren't in `rerenderPropsList`?

Comment: @CertainPerformance what do you mean by that? can you elaborate more on that please? or create a discussion in the package, that's better if it long explanation

Answer (score 0):

You can't render an object this way, if you want to render it just for debugging, you can use `JSON.stringify`, if you want to actually render the data, you need to display each of the primitive values separately.