# Unexpected behaviour of useState hook

Tags: reactjs, use-state

I was trying out an image mapper library and found an unexpected behaviour. The handler function `handleInc` behaves differently depending on whether its triggered by the `+` button or via clicking on the highlighted area in the image (need to move mouse around in order for highlighted area to appear).

When using `+` button the behaviour is as expected but when clicking highlighted area in the image, the state variable `count` doesn't seems to go beyound `1`.

What's the reason for behind the same function `handleInc` behaving differently.

Here is the code ([sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-image-mapperissue-jpis4?file=/src/App.js:0-1756) for the code below)

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
// https://github.com/img-mapper/react-img-mapper
import ImageMapper from "react-img-mapper";

const URL =
  "https://helpx.adobe.com/content/dam/help/en/stock/how-to/visual-reverse-image-search/jcr_content/main-pars/image/visual-reverse-image-search-v2_intro.jpg";

export default function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const handleInc = () => {
    // this print expected value when + button is clicked
    // but print 0 if highlighted area is clicked
    console.log(count);
    setCount(count + 1);
  };
  const handleDec = () => {
    console.log(count);
    setCount(count - 1);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <button onClick={handleInc}>+</button>
      {count}
      <button onClick={handleDec}>-</button>

      <ImageMapper
        src={URL}
        map={{
          name: "asdf",
          areas: [
            {
              id: 0,
              active: true,
              title: "BB(1-4)",
              shape: "poly",
              name: "BB(1-4)",
              fillColor: "#eab54d4d",
              strokeColor: "black",
              coords: [
                260,
                142,
                77,
                196,
                184,
                530,
                840,
                529,
                928,
                283,
                894,
                26,
                389,
                53,
                343,
                31,
                321,
                90
              ]
            }
          ]
        }}
        stayMultiHighlighted
        onClick={handleInc}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: react-img-mapper is a clone of react-image-mapper. You might have missed that. react-image-mapper is not maintained and i address this react-img-mapper is created

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems that the `ImageMapper` component is memoizing the callbacks, in other words, it has closed over the initial `count` state value and never updates from that point.

If you use a functional state update then clicking the highlighted area seems to work as I think you expect it to. Functional state updates work by updating from the previous state versus the state from render cycle the callback was enqueued in.

```
const handleInc = () => {
  setCount(count => count + 1);
};

const handleDec = () => {
  setCount(count => count - 1);
};
```

## Demo

[image: Edit unexpected-behaviour-of-usestate-hook]

Comment: thanks for pointing it out. Although i knew functional state update would fix the problem I didn't exactly knew why. Any docs which you might suggest for understanding this type of behaviour of memoization?

Comment: @RishabhSingh I don't know of any docs off-hand, but mostly know and recognize this issue from empirical observation and experience. A counter is even the de facto [example](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous) React uses to explain functional state updates since each update *depends* on the value of the previous state.

Comment: I just wanted to have little more insight on how memoization works. I deliberatley made count variable just to make things simple. Seems like ImageMapper take a snapshot of handleInc, along with the snapshot of count variable which was 0 at that moment. And later for all clicks, it keeps using that snapshot 0 instead of the actual count state variable. Am i somewhat right :- |

Comment: Hello @RishabhSingh, I am the owner of `react-img-mapper`, yes I am memorized the callbacks that's why you got the initial value of that but as @patrick said you can use `rerenderProps` or as I said to you in the mail you can use the previous callback of the state to update your state, Thanks

Comment: @RishabhSingh You are pretty much on the nose with that. In simplest terms, memoization is simply a way to "speed up" computing by storing the result of a function call, and in this case it was the version of `handleInc` from that component's initial render cycle. Your buttons worked because they get a new copy of `handleInc` each render, but the Image-mapper component used the cached version.

Comment: @Nisharg Shah so lets say if i only wanted to get the value of count inside onClick handler even then I will have to to include the handler in rerenderProps.

Comment: no, if you are using `previous` callback of state then there is no need to include the `onClick` on `rerenderProps`, you are good to go but if you are referencing the count variable in `useState` and not using `previous` callback then you need to include it

Comment: I have already given that solution to you in the mail and @DrewReese explain you very well and patrick also gives a nice alternative

Comment: @Nisharg Shah lets say if my click handler (i.e. `handleInc`)only has `console.log(count)` in it. Even then I would have to include `onClick` in `rerenderProps` due to which I loose highlighted area due to rerender

Comment: you can use this `setCount(count => {/* your logic */; return count;})` hack, so you will get latest count without including the `onClick` prop in `rerenderProps`

Answer (score 3):

[`ImageMapper` is indeed memoized](https://github.com/img-mapper/react-img-mapper/blob/2e03440f57f0219e99198a5ac809141473a3dca8/src/ImageMapper.tsx#L383-L389). [Drew's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66963057/1541563) is correct and the recommended practice for [calling the `setState` hook callback when the state update depends on its previous value](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates).

Alternatively, the interface for the `ImageMapper` component has a [`rerenderProps`](https://github.com/img-mapper/react-img-mapper#properties) property you can specify to add `onClick` to its sensitivity list and override memoization:

```
<ImageMapper
  ...
  onClick={handleInc}
  rendererProps={['onClick']}
/>
```

Comment: Thanks for exactly poiniting out the code. Any docs which you might suggest for understanding this type of behaviour of memoization?

Comment: @RishabhSingh well, there's the link that's already in my answer about [functional updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates), and then there's this one about [`React.memo()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo), which `ImageMapper` uses to memoize its props.

Comment: Thanks for digging into my code and also for finding a very nice alternative

Comment: @NishargShah thank you for making your source code easy to read :) very helpful

Comment: Welcome, your compliment is a huge acceleration for me.